# Deprecated express-session options in using express-socket.io-session,why it occurs?

Tags: node.js, session, express, socket.io

So I am using the [express-socket.io-session module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session) and I tried to copy in my code what the example said in the documentation. Upon doing so however, I keep encountering these warnings:

```
express-session deprecated undefined resave option;
express-session deprecated undefined saveUninitialized option;
express-session deprecated req.secret;
```

My version of express is 4.13.4 and socket.io is 1.4.5 which is supported according to the documentation. I have no idea why it keeps saying deprecated.

Here is how I initialize my express-session and express-socket.io-session :

```
var expressSession = require('express-session');
var sharedSession = require('express-socket.io-session');
app.use(expressSession({secret:'surfsocial2016',
                        resave: true,
                        saveUninitialized: true
                        })
                      );

io.use(sharedSession(expressSession,{autoSave:true}));
```

Below is my socket code :

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log(socket.handshake.session.room);
    socket.on('send message', function(data){
        console.log(data["message"]);
        io.emit('new message', data["message"]);
    });
});
```

My 'send message' event does not work as well because nothing happens with it whenever i emit something from the client side. I think this is because of the deprecated warnings. Everything works okay if i remove the `io.use(sharedSession(expressSession,{autoSave:true}));` line which is why I am suspecting the issue is with those deprecated warnings.

Am I initializing the variables wrong?